# Nginx with Windows or Linux

Tags: linux, node.js, windows, nginx

I want to use `Nginx` as a web server for `NodeJS`.

I know that Nginx's platform is Linux, but does it means that the performance/benefits would be better if I run it on Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the below link to know about the limitations of running Nginx on Windows: http://nginx.org/en/docs/windows.html

Comment: Thanks. Thats good. After I read it I understand that probably Nginx as a web server is not that good if I use Windows. Probably I will use NodeJS too as a web server.